# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type..

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, pagedlist

I'm developing a simple project with mvc3. created two models Customer & call.
In CustomerController i used PagedList for paging. I shown paging on Index view of customer. I want to show last 5 records calls list on the customers index view. I created partial view for Call's index view. I used partial view of call on customer index page as following way--

```
@Html.Partial("IndexCallPartial")
```

But it is showing the error after selecting Customer index page. The error is as follows-

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`1[graceCRM.Models.Customer]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'graceCRM.Models.Call'.
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self explanatory. The view in which you are calling the `Html.Partial` helper is strongly typed to the `PagedList<Customer>` class. And by default `@Html.Partial("IndexCallPartial")` is equivalent to `@Html.Partial("IndexCallPartial", Model)`. This means that it is an instance of `PagedList<Customer>` that will be passed to your partial. But your partial doesn't expect such instance. The error message tells you the instance it expects.

So to fix this you need to pass the correct instance:

```
@Html.Partial("IndexCallPartial", some_instance_of_the_correct_type_the_partial_expects)
```